# Duplication of unit tests in devops

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-devops

I'm creating `pipeline` in `devops` and `vstests` doesn't pass. I have some unit tests that are faulty but I want to keep them. So I've added the `[Ignore]` attribute to those. When I push commit I can see that those tests are duplicated and one in fact is skipped but the other is failed. Can someone nudge me why this might be happening?

Comment: Are you using a hosted agent ? could it be that your assembly is build twice ?

Comment: I hope it's not the greenest question but how can I check if I'm using a hosted agent?

Comment: Yes, I believe I use a hosted agent. But I have little to no knowledge about this.

Comment: When you edit your build, select "Pipeline" on the left and look for "Agent pool", there should be a dropdown for selecting the pool then

Comment: i think your assembly is located twice in your build, thats why one test is ignored (latest assembly) and the other one is processed (older assembly). Can you go to "Get sources" and set "Clean" to "true" and on "Clean options" select "Sources and output directory" and then retry your build/tests

Comment: I'm not sure if I cana manage the Agent Pools since it's for organization, this "Get sources" is managed in Agent Pools or somewhere else? Because I cannot find it.

Comment: the settings i mentioned are all in the build-editor, no need to access organization settings here

Comment: `Azure Pipelines: To specify the source repository, while editing your pipeline, click the YAML or Tasks tab, then click Get sources, and then select the type of repo that contains your source files.` I have a Tasks tab but there aren't `Get sources`

Comment: Ok, I've found it under `Variables` tab.

Comment: I've changed it and still the same issue.

Comment: could it be possible that you build your test assembly multiple times ? as debug and release for example ? if you are using a hosted agent you get a new machine on every build so it can't be an older assembly from a previous build

Comment: There must be two versions executing of tests. I don't know how to check this. Thanks for the help nontheless.